# which hook in wordpress is used for making custom login URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plug-in for wordpress for custom url(url other than wp-admin.php and wp-login.php) and need to know the required hook to be used for this

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Page redirection in Wordpress should be handled by the template_redirect hook, because at that point the WP object (which contains the post information) is available. For a full list of available hooks and when to use them see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

However, in your case I would highly suggest using htaccess rewriting instead of PHP redirecting. You can set your plugin to write to the .htaccess. By using the .htaccess mod_rewrite module you can, for example, redirect users who try to access wp-login.php directly to a 404 page and then define a different url to redirect to the actual wp-login.php file.